# Makefile in linux: what is the reason I can overwrite files without permission?

Tags: file-permissions

Can someone explain to me why `make` can freely overwrite existing files? For instance:

```
JAVA_FILES = example.java, example2.java

submit: example.zip

example.zip: $(JAVA_FILES)
zip $@ $^
```

In the terminal, not-rooted I type this and get what I expect:

```
user@computer :~$ make submit
zip example.zip example.java, example2.java
adding: example.java (deflated 53%)
adding: example2.java (deflated 53%)
```

What I did not expect is that if I now make a small change to `example.java` (for instance), and `make submit` again, the old file is overwritten without any kind of prompting. How is it possible that it doesn't need (my) permission to overwrite or sudo?

Comment: Is that operation being done in a directory owned by root? What are the permissions on the files in question and on the directory itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If -- on your behalf -- `make` can *create* the `.zip` file in the first place, then there's no special reason to suppose that `make` cannot also *modify* the file on your behalf.  The `make` program is not operating as some independent third party: when *you* run it, it is operating as *you* (for whatever the current sense of "you" is).  The only reason to suppose that it might have a permission issue is if your default umask is set to disallow you modifying files you create, say `0222`.  That would be very unusual, and inconvenient.

Comment: To put it another way, by running a program you implicitly give your permission for whatever actions that program attempts to perform.

Comment: So it's an extra feature when in windows you are being asked to overwrite a file? For instance in paint you create a new file and save it as a new already existing in the same folder. Can paint also just overwrite a file without asking first?

Comment: If a program prompts you before overwriting a file, then that's a feature *of that program*.  It is relatively common for some kinds of programs, but not for other kinds.  It really has nothing to do with operating system.  For example, if you ask VisualStudio to rebuild a project, it doesn't prompt you about replacing the project's target files.